# "Who was that [masked] tag?" (or: what to w/what shows up in tag browser for "[mask]")

Tags: discussion, retag-request, synonym-request

Here is what Wikipedia has to say about [Mask (computing)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mask_(computing)).

If you click on the very general [mask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mask) (386), [masking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/masking) (194), and [masked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/masked) (20) tags, what you wind up with is a hodgepodge.  I'd ban those terms but have "mask" provoke more specific ones in the tag prompter.  What specific ones?  Well, the questions appear fit into these categories:

- **bit masking** - how to turn 0xDECAFBAD into 0x00000BAD, that sort of thing.  There are tags for [bitmask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bitmask) (117) and [bit-masks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bit-masks) (6), but a fair number of the general mask questions fit here.  I think the best name for this tag would be `bit-masking`.
- **image masking** - As per Wiki, this is essentially an implementation method for clipping/transparency which uses a bit mask.  Lots of functions in APIs exist with "Mask" or "ClipMask" in the name, and so a fair number of the general mask questions fit here as well.    Few have bothered to narrow this one...but there is [opacitymask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opacitymask) (21), [cgimagemaskcreate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cgimagemaskcreate) (3), [cgimagecreatewithmask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cgimagecreatewithmask) (3), and the unused but somehow still alive tags [transparency-mask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/transparency-mask) (0) and [image-masking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/image-masking) (0).  I would steer these to `image-masking`, which may or may not make a good synonym for `transparency-mask`.
- **input filtering** - Our friends at [Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox(v=vs.80).aspx), [jQuery community](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7935233/jquery-inputmask-plugin), and elsewhere want to call it "input masking" when you are trying to constrain the typing to match a format string.  I don't use the word "mask" this way, and Wikipedia doesn't mention it either.  So I'd personally retag [maskedinput](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/maskedinput) (30) questions as [input-filtering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/input-filtering) (20), and throw in `input-masking` as a synonym for `input-filtering` to help anyone typing in a question.  Some domain-specific tags that may or may not be valuable to keep in their own right are [maskedtextbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/maskedtextbox) (84), [maskededittextender](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/maskededittextender) (40), [jquery-mask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-mask) (9), [maskededitvalidator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/maskededitvalidator) (5).  The [radmaskededitbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/radmaskededitbox) (4) should be merged with [telerik-radmaskedtextbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/telerik-radmaskedtextbox) (2), and I don't know if ([telerik] [radmaskededitbox]) is the better solution than [telerik-radmaskedtextbox] or not.
- **webkit-mask-image** - this is a very particular [non-standard CSS extension](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/-webkit-mask-image) that probably deserves its own tag for questions that deal with this.  There is one [webkit-mask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/webkit-mask) (2) with only two uses, but there seem to be a lot of questions about it in the pool.  I would rename it to `webkit-mask-image`.
- **autoresizingmask** - Another very-specific thing, this time [an iOS feature](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html) [autoresizingmask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/autoresizingmask) (66): *"An integer bit mask that determines how the receiver resizes itself when its superview’s bounds change"*.  I don't care what that means, but it's obviously something other people care about and deserves to keep its tag.
- **umask** is a [unix command](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umask), and the [umask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/umask) (23) questions probably belong on another StackExchange.
- **netmask** is that thing that most of the time is 255.255.255.0, and I'd probably redirect [netmask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/netmask) (17) as a synonym for the more descriptive `subnet-mask`.
- **domain masking** is something about [hiding URLs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Masking), and [url-masking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/url-masking) (12) plus [domain-mask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/domain-mask) (7) should be redirected to [domain-masking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/domain-masking) (10).

There's also two functions with "mask" in the name that show up, [setthreadaffinitymask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/setthreadaffinitymask) (10) and [sigprocmask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sigprocmask) (6)...and I guess those are fine as they are.

So to sum up:

1. mask/masking/masked questions get sorted and after that these tags go away.
2. main umbrella terms after the change are `bit-masking`, `image-masking`, and `input-masking` which maps to `input-filtering`.
3. well-defined stuff that just has "mask" in the name sticks around.